# Selenium xpath getting changed during run time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario - Valid login to www.homeshop18.com and then from the Digital Menu select "Samsung".
The results are displayed and now I need to choose another brand - Micromax from the Brand section (displayed at the left side of the page) 
which requires scrolling and selecting Micromax.

Issue:

Though the xpath of Micromax is correct which is //*[@id='filter_1Option_12']//div[@class='ez-checkbox'] but I see during run time of the script - some other brand is getting selected instead of micromax.
Kindly advise.

//Class for valid login to www.homeshop18.com

```
public class HomeShop_Login_Test 
{
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@id='signInHeaderLink']") WebElement SignIn_Link;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//input[@id='emailId']") WebElement Email;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//input[@id='existing_user_radio']") WebElement Existing_User_Radio;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//input[@id='new_user_radio']") WebElement New_User_Radio;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//input[@id='password']") WebElement Password;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//a[@id='signin']") WebElement SignIn_Button;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Close']") WebElement Close_Home;


    public void Login_Valid()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        WebElement SignIn_Link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='signInHeaderLink']")));

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", SignIn_Link);

        Email.sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
        boolean selected;

        selected = New_User_Radio.isSelected();

        if(selected)
        {
            Existing_User_Radio.click();
        }

        Password.sendKeys("xxx");
        SignIn_Button.click();


    }

//Class to choose Samsung from Digital menu

public class Browse_Samsung_Mobile 
{

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='CategoryMenu1']//a[text()='Digital']") WebElement Digital_Menu;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='CategoryMenu1']//a[@title='Samsung']") WebElement Samsung_SubMenu;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='filter_1Option_19']//span[@class='selected_filter_img']") WebElement Micromax;

    public void Browse_Samsung() 
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(Digital_Menu).perform();
        act.click(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='CategoryMenu1']//a[@title='Samsung']")))).build().perform();

        //WebElement Micromax = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_1Option_12']//span[@class='selected_filter_img']")));

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Micromax);

    }
}

//class to call above two classes

public class Validate_Browse_Samsung_Mobile 
{

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void Validate_Browse() 
    {
        driver = BrowserFactory.getBrowser("Firefox");
        driver.get(DataProviderFactory.getConfig().getURL());
        HomeShop_Login_Test login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomeShop_Login_Test.class);
        login.Login_Valid();
        Browse_Samsung_Mobile browse = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Browse_Samsung_Mobile.class);
        browse.Browse_Samsung();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with their name using `title` attribute as below :-

```
WebElement micromax = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[title ~= "Micromax"] input")));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! 
Though now my script is able to click "micromax" correctly but I am not able to see the click. Is there a way, I can make my script scroll which can be viewed by me too?
Currently I am using this script but this is not letting see the click.
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Micromax);

Comment: Yes you can scroll first to view click as `((JavascriptExexutor)driver).exexuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", micromax);
micromax.click();`...

Comment: Tried but no luck. Kindly check.

WebElement Micromax = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_1Option_21']//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']")));
  
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView", Micromax);
  Micromax.click();
Error;
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 20.15 seconds

Comment: Change `arguments[0].scrollIntoView` to `arguments[0].scrollIntoView()` ...:)

Comment: tried both but same error..
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Micromax);
  Micromax.click();
  
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Micromax);
  Micromax.click();  
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='filter_1Option_21']//a[@title='GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax']

Answer (score 0):

You should use following `XPath` to choose proper check-box:

```
//a[@title="GSM Mobile Phones - Micromax"]/div/input
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! 
Though now my script is able to click "micromax" correctly but I am not able to see the click. Is there a way, I can make my script scroll which can be viewed by me too?
Currently I am using this script but this is not letting see the click.
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Micromax);